# ActionView::MissingTemplate after Rails 3.1 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, actionview, missing-template

After upgrading to Rails 3.1.0 and following [David Rice's instructions](http://davidjrice.co.uk/2011/05/25/how-to-upgrade-a-rails-application-to-version-3-1-0.html), all of my controllers strangely can't find their views anymore.

```
# rails s #

Started GET "/units" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-04 07:52:23 -0400
  Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "units".* FROM "units" 

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template units/index, application/index with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:
):
  app/controllers/units_controller.rb:9:in `index'
```

`units_controller.rb`:

```
  # GET /units
  # GET /units.xml
  def index
    @units = Unit.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @units }
    end
  end
```

Of course, the view is there (`/app/views/units/index.html.erb`; it was working before the upgrade). I feel this is a stupid error, what am I missing here?

Comment: I'm not getting this same error on localhost but I'm getting it on Heroku for some unfathomable reason. Did anybody else see this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to remove the following line in your development.rb:

config.action_view.debug_rjs             = true

This should be removed or commented out when not using Rail Javascript.

See the "jQuery: New Default" on rubyonrails.org for more information on upgrading
http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/4/21/jquery-new-default

Answer (score 2):

Like Tom said, I had originally forgotten to remove

```
config.action_view.debug_rjs = true
```

in `/config/environments/development.rb`, but at the time I posted the question, I had done it already.

The thing though (quite stupid) is that I had to **restart the server after changing a *config* parameter**. Restart your servers when you change your config settings, kids!

Answer (score 0):

The views are saved as erb, not haml? Just stabbing in the dark...

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, but for a different reason.  I had my RAILS_ENV set to development when I ran my cucumber tests.

`export RAILS_ENV=`  or `export RAILS_ENV=test` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

rails generate controller Welcome index will generate the controller , I guess this is the easiest way to generate the controller

Answer (score 0):

If you're upgrading an old app that's been around since Rails v1, you might have xml templates named as .rxml. This is no longer supported in Rails 3.1(where it was in 3.0), so they need to be renamed to .builder.

What was:

```
units.xml.rxml
```

Needs to be renamed to:

```
units.xml.builder
```

This would affect all templates that uses the XML builder. e.g. RSS, KML etc.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this problem because some of my templates were still named `.rhtml` instead of `.erb.html`